# How do you make use of a counter with recursion in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, counter

I'm trying to write a simple "password" program in Python that allows 3 attempts at "logging in" with a recursive function. I can't figure out why it's not working though... (And yes, Jurassic Park inspired)

```
def magicWord(count):
    int(count)
    answer = raw_input("What is the password? ")
    if answer == 'lucas':
        print 'ACESS GRANTED'
    else:
        count =+ 1
        if count > 2:
            while count > 2:
                count+=1
                print "na na na you didn\'t say the magic word. "
        else:
            magicWord(count)

magicWord(0)
```

Comment: Do you mean `count+=1` after `else:`?

Comment: The line with `int(count)` doesn't do anything: `int(..)` returns its argument converted to an integer, it doesn't affect its argument.

Comment: why do you want to use recursion? It doesn't seem at all needed here. is this homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close.  There were just a couple minor fix-ups:

```
def magicWord(count):
    answer = raw_input("What is the password? ")
    if answer == 'lucas':
        print 'ACESS GRANTED'
    else:
        count += 1
        if count > 2:
            print "na na na you didn\'t say the magic word. "
            return
        else:
            magicWord(count)
```

Here's a sample session:

```
>>> magicWord(0)
What is the password? alan
What is the password? ellie
What is the password? ian
na na na you didn't say the magic word.
```

Comment: Aw, you removed the original's infinite loop that relates to the Jurassic Park insipred log-in!

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a recursion? My variant don't use it and it seems easier

```
def magic_word(attempts):
   for attempt in range(attempts):
      answer = raw_input("What is the password? ")
      if answer == 'lucas':
          return True
   return False

if magic_word(3):
   print 'ACESS GRANTED'
else:
   print "na na na you didn\'t say the magic word. "
```

Comment: Yes the question does say to use recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!  Recursion without hardcoding the number of attempts within the function:

```
def magicword(attempts):
    valid_pw = ['lucas']
    if attempts:
        answer = raw_input('What is the password?')
        if answer in valid_pw:
            return True
        else:
            return magicword(attempts -1)

if magicword(3):
    print 'you got it right'
else:
    print "na na na you didn't say the magic word"
```

returns:

```
What is the password?ian
What is the password?elli
What is the password?bob
na na na you didn't say the magic word
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
What is the password?ian
What is the password?lucas
you got it right
```